# Convert generic type definition strings from C# style to CLR style

Tags: c#, string, generics, clr

I want to convert a C# style generic type **string**, like:

```
"System.Dictionary<System.String, System.String>"
```

To its CLR equivalent:

```
"System.Dictionary`1[System.String, System.String]"
```

and back. Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to resort to string manipulation?

**EDIT:**

I only have the *string representation* in C#/VB/etc style form. I don't have a Type object or something similar at hand. An alternate question would have been: how to get a Type object from a string representation like `"System.Dictionary<System.String, System.String>"` (after that I can get the full name of the type object).

**EDIT#2:**

Justification: I'm creating objects dynamically using `CodeDom`. The input from which I'm generating the `CodeDom` might contain types in `C#` (or any other proprietary like VB.NET) format, but I have to use them inside a `CodeTypeReference`, which only accepts the CLR style format.

Comment: You are looking for a lot of pain if you try to convert the `C#` style to the actual .Net type.   Your best bet make be to create a lookup table related to your CodeDOM code.  It would contain the list of `C#` types and .Net Type names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I faced a similar issue in the past and wrote the following utility method to address it :

```
    // Utilitiy to convert class name string to namespace-qualified name
    public static Type GetTypeByName(string ClassName, 
        string TypesNamespacePrefix = "AssemblyTopLevel.AssemblyMidLevel.", 
        Dictionary<string, Type> ConcreteTypeMap = null)
    {
        if ((ConcreteTypeMap != null) && (ConcreteTypeMap.ContainsKey(ClassName)))
            return ConcreteTypeMap[ClassName];

        if ((ConcreteTypeMap != null) && (ConcreteTypeMap.ContainsKey(TypesNamespacePrefix + ClassName)))
            return ConcreteTypeMap[TypesNamespacePrefix + ClassName];

        try
        {
            if (Type.GetType(ClassName) != null)
                return Type.GetType(ClassName);
        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            if (Type.GetType(TypesNamespacePrefix + ClassName) != null)
                return Type.GetType(TypesNamespacePrefix + ClassName);
        }
        catch { }

        Stack<int> GenericCounterStack = new Stack<int>();
        Stack<int> GenericStartIndexStack = new Stack<int>();
        Dictionary<int, int> GenericCountMapByStartIndex = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        int Count = 1;
        int GenericStartIndex = -1;
        int PreviousHighestGenericIndex = -1;

        foreach (char c in ClassName)
        {
            if (c.Equals('<'))
            {
                if (GenericStartIndex != -1)
                {
                    GenericCounterStack.Push(Count);
                    GenericStartIndexStack.Push(GenericStartIndex);
                }
                Count = 1;
                GenericStartIndex = PreviousHighestGenericIndex + 1;
                PreviousHighestGenericIndex = Math.Max(GenericStartIndex, PreviousHighestGenericIndex);
            }
            else if (c.Equals(','))
            {
                Count++;
            }
            else if (c.Equals('>'))
            {
                GenericCountMapByStartIndex[GenericStartIndex] = Count;
                if (GenericCounterStack.Count != 0)
                    Count = GenericCounterStack.Pop();
                if (GenericStartIndexStack.Count != 0)
                    GenericStartIndex = GenericStartIndexStack.Pop();
            }
        }

        ClassName = ClassName.Replace("<" + TypesNamespacePrefix, "<");

        StringBuilder FullyQualifiedClassName = new StringBuilder(TypesNamespacePrefix);

        GenericStartIndex = 0;
        foreach (char c in ClassName)
        {
            if (c.Equals('<'))
            {
                FullyQualifiedClassName.Append("`" + GenericCountMapByStartIndex[GenericStartIndex].ToString()
                    + "[" + TypesNamespacePrefix);
                GenericStartIndex++;
            }
            else if (c.Equals(','))
            {
                FullyQualifiedClassName.Append("," + TypesNamespacePrefix);
            }
            else if (c.Equals('>'))
            {
                FullyQualifiedClassName.Append("]");
            }
            else
                FullyQualifiedClassName.Append(c);
        }

        ClassName = FullyQualifiedClassName.ToString();

        return Type.GetType(ClassName);
    }
```

You may optionally provide a concrete type map, to optimize for commonly-invoked cases:

```
static readonly Dictionary <string, Type> MyConcreteTypeMap = new Dictionary<string,Type>()
    {
        {"SomeClass", typeof(SomeClass)},
        {"AnotherClass", typeof(AnotherClass)}
    }
```

So, the invocation looks like this:

```
Type DesiredType = GetTypeByName("SomeClass", "", MyConcreteTypeMap);
```

or

```
Type DesiredType = GetTypeByName("SomeOtherClass", "MyAssemblyTopLevel.MyAssemblyMidLevel.");
```

or

```
Type DesiredType = GetTypeByName("SomeOtherClass");
```

or, quite usefully,

```
Type DesiredType = GetTypeByName("SomeOtherClass<OuterTemplate<InnerTemplate1,InnerTemplate2<InnerInnerTemplate1>>>");
```

or, for the original example,

```
Type DesiredType = GetTypeByName("Dictionary<String,String>", "System.");
```

Answer (score 4):

For the .NET to C# direction, I can't see an easy way to do it; you may have to actually parse the type yourself.

In the other direction, it's pretty easy:

```
public static string DotNetToCSharp(string tyName) {
    var provider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
    return provider.GetTypeOutput(new System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReference(tyName));
}
```

Comment: for the other way it seems i have to resort to codesnippets (or parse it by hand)

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof(System.Dictionary<System.String>, System.String>).FullName
```

As for the reverse, no clue :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand your question.
Anyway -when you instantiate a genetic class `Class<T1, ... ,Tn>` the defined in namespace Namespace, for example

```
Namespace.Class<T1, ... ,Tn> a = new Namespace.Class<Type1,...,Typen>();
```

a.GetType().FullName will give you the full string representation of the class
which will be `"Namespace.Class'n<Type1,...,Typen>"`

Answer (score 0):

`typeof(System.Dictionary<System.String, System.String>).FullName` should get you something like:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

Might need to do some replacement on the full type names inside the type parameter spec. However if you use the below code

```
typeof(Dictionary<System.String, System.String>).ToString()
```

You will get something like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
```

To convert back into a `Type` use

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]");
```

**EDIT** I've tried hacking this with dynamic expressions but didn't have much luck. I think, other than parsing the string, you can use a "nuclear option" and compile a DLL using [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) and then load it using [`Assembly.LoadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) and execute a method that will evaluate typeof(...).

Comment: I only have the string representation of the type in C# style. See edit.

Comment: Hmm. Not something one would want to do normally. If you have C# code, you compile it. If you have string representation of a type, it's normally serialised to string and then deserialised. Both of those cases are supported by the framework. Could you provide more context about what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were looking for...

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var type = dict.GetType();
var typeName = type.FullName;
var newType = Type.GetType(typeName);

Console.WriteLine(type == newType); //true
```

Comment: I only have the string representation of the type in C# style

Comment: @SztupY: If you want to make an instance of the object/type you may be able to use CodeDom instead of string manipulation.  But you best bet would probably be to write some sort of converter/parser for the string values.  It is an option to replace the `C#` style values with the correct `Type.FullName` or `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`?